# Cypher variable length path optimisation

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a graph with a structure like this:

[image: Sample graph]

I need to return all the return all `:Treasure` which was not `:FOUND_BY` more than 1 `:User`, either directly (red path), or via their `:Group` (blue path).

My cypher

```
MATCH (t:Treasure)
// WHERE with other conditions
WITH t, SIZE((t)-[:FOUND_BY|MEMBER_OF*1..2]-(:User))) as finders
WHERE finders < 2
RETURN t
```

returns the nodes I'm looking for, but spends horrendous time on expanding that variable path.
How could I optimise this cypher, get rid of the variable path, but keep the same results?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you could just do

```
MATCH (t:Treasure)
WHERE size((t)-[:FOUND_BY]->()) < 2
RETURN t
```

You can omit the label on the other side of the `[:FOUND_BY]` relationship so that you take both cases into account. Let me know if I'm misunderstanding.

Edit: Per your comment I think the best way to avoid the variable-length path is:

```
MATCH (t:Treasure)
WHERE size((t)-[:FOUND_BY]->(:User)) + 
      size((t)-[:FOUND_BY]->(:Group)<-[:MEMBER_OF]-(:User)) < 2
RETURN t
```

Comment: That's not the same. I have to count the `:User` nodes, not the number of the relationships. A `:Group` without any member should not count.

Comment: thanks, but that will count `(a:User)<-[:FOUND_BY]-(t)-[:FOUND_BY]->(:Group)<-[:MEMBER_OF]-(a)`  (same user directly and indirectly related to t) as 2.

Comment: If you already have that redundancy in your graph then you can simply check the size of `(:Treasure)-[:FOUND_BY]->(:User)`.

Comment: I do not always have that, but it can happen. That's why I used the variable path, and that's why I need to count distinct users.